# Crystal report viewer tool bar images not displayed in development in Asp.net

Tags: crystal-reports

We are using crystal report 11.5 in vs. 2008 to display report in one of my projects, when I try to display a report in crystal report viewer reports are displayed properly but the toolbar icons (First, Prev, Next, print, etc..) images are not getting displayed and on click of any of these buttons the report vanishes giving a blank page. the images for the same are also available at the path `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\2_0_50727\crystalreportviewers115`. Please let me know if there any other thing to be done.

```
<CR1:CrystalReportViewer id="CrystalReportViewer1" style="Z-INDEX: 102; LEFT: 8px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 32px" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="350px" ></CR1:CrystalReportViewer>
```

Thanks,
Arvind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Analyze the problem

It's possible to analyze the problem

- using **client tools** (debug window of browser)

> GET http://myserver:20080/aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js 403 (Forbidden)
>   GET http://myserver:20080/aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/images/style.css 403 (Forbidden)

- or **server tool** (IIS log , on WIN2003 is placed in `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\LogFiles\W3SVC###\`).

> 2011-03-28 13:00:49 W3SVC701536 95.228.38.41 GET /aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/images/style.css - 20080 - 192.168.1.2 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/5.0) 403 6 64 Errore!
>   2011-03-28 13:00:49 W3SVC701536 95.228.38.41 GET /aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js - 20080 - 192.168.1.2 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/5.0) 403 6 64 Errore!

### Cause the problem

- In both cases i found that `crv.js` and `style.css` some files were not served;
- these files are placed by CR installer in `wwwroot\aspnet_client` folder, but for some reasons they cannot be reached;
- In my case the reason is that i create a **different website (port 20080) and aspnet_client folder is not placed inside that website**

I can see that you use different versions of software and different configurations, but **i think you have the same problem**.

### Solution

The solution is to work on IIS  this way:

- **Copy `aspnet_client` folder** from `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` folder to the **new website root folder**.

or

- **Create a virtual directory** called `aspnet_client` that points to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` **inside the new website**

Answer (score 1):

Shall you check ReportViewer properities, so many properities are there to set report viewer toolbar buttons?

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="rptViewer" runat="server" HasPageNavigationButtons="True" HasGotoPageButton="True" CssClass="report" />
```