# Crystal Report IE7, IE8, IE 10 design issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports-2010

I have simple questions that surely someone can help me with.
Am using Visual Studio 2010, Framework 4.0 and Crystal Report.

Have a report that looks different depending on which browser you use.
How does it look at these different browsers

IE 7:

[image: IE7 Version]

IE 9

[image: IE9 Version]

IE 10

[image: IE10 Version]

In all cases, I can't see the full toolbar. What could be the problem?

Many thanks

Comment: If it looks exactly the same in every version of IE, I can only assume, there isn't suppose to be a toolbar.  Your title doesn't match the list of versions of IE you have tested.

Comment: adding this code
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,chrome=1" />



Crystal Report Issue with IIS
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101157/crystal-report-viewer-tool-bar-images-not-displayed-in-development-in-asp-net